# How to insert text of image or simply text via URL on PHP file?

Tags: php, url-parameters

I need to know if it is possible to, for example, in `home.php` display an image but have the image name be given by url.

For example, have `home.php?=IMAGENAME` display `IMAGENAME.jpg`.

Or even just working with text, have `home.php?=TEXT` display "Welcome to TEXT"

Comment: http://www.php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.get.php

Answer (score 1):

Use `$_GET`.

If URL is `http://mysite.com/?image=myimage.jpeg`, then

```
$image = $_GET['image'];
echo $image; // 'myimage.jpeg'
```

Be careful though, since that would let anyone put anything in the URL and it would go to your code. You should validate it, escape it, etc, depending upon what you use it for.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it's possible.

You can use $_GET, to do it:

```
if ($_GET['image'] != "")
{
$img = htmlspecialchars($_GET['image']);
echo "<h3>".$_GET['image']."</h3><br><img src='http://yoursite.com/images/".$_GET['image']."'>";
} else {
exit ("No image here =(");
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Pass to your home.php a variable containing the string url.

es:`home.php?url=img/your_img.jpg OR home.php?url=your_img.jpg`

Then add to your img tag that:`<img src="<?echo($_GET['url'])?>">`

And it display your img from the url that you pass through the principal url.

For text it work the same way: `home.php?text=yeah`

Then in html `<p><? echo($_GET['text']) ?></p>` and you are done!